# Stop the 'Ding' when pressing Enter

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, system-sounds

I have a very simple Windows Forms Application. And, in Windows (or, atleast Windows Forms Applications), when you press Enter while inside a Single-line TextBox Control, you hear a Ding. It's an unpleasent sound, that indicated you cannot enter a newline, because it is a single-line TextBox.

This is all fine. However, in my Form, I have 1 TextBox, and a Search Button. And I am allowing the user to Perform a search by pressing Enter after they've finished typing, so they don't *have* to use the mouse to click the Search Button.

But this Ding sound occurs. It's very annoying.

How can we make it so just that sound doesn't play at all in my Form?

@David H - Here's how I'm detecting the enter pressing:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Perform search now.
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect that Enter has been pressed when the focus is in the text box?

Comment: In the Properties Pane, you double-click the KeyDown or KeyUp Event. Then, in Code View, you type the code that I'm about to put in my question for yah.

Comment: KeyPress is probably the right event, and you want to set e.Handled = true

Comment: I wish there was some way to suppress the annoying ding but allow the key press to bubble up. Sometimes a key press is just a key press, no need for alarm.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check out the [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property. You can use it to specify a default button for a form, in this case for pressing enter.

From the docs:

> This property enables you to designate
>   a default action to occur when the
>   user presses the ENTER key in your
>   application. The button assigned to
>   this property must be an
>   IButtonControl that is on the current
>   form or located within a container on
>   the current form.

There is also a [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) property for when the user presses escape.

Comment: Thank you @mdm, this worked the best for me. :) I will come back to upvote when I have more rep.

Comment: @bendr i have the same problem .. but im using UserControl .. it doesn't have Form.AcceptButton .. how to fix it?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't seem to have a field in the Properties pane for this. It has to be done in code, apparently. `this.AcceptButton = buttonOK; this.CancelButton = buttonCancel;`

Comment: This won't work for ToolStripButtons or if you want to use the ENTER key to validate a TextBox or ToolStripTextBox. The better approach would be the answer of Lucio Fonseca which worked for me with ToolStripTextBox.

Comment: I can not see your solution you do not have a practical exercise to be more enlightened

Answer (score 256):

It works for me:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    //Se apertou o enter
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //enter key is down

        this.doSomething();

        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

     }

 }
```

The SuppressKeyPress is the really trick. I hope that help you.

Comment: This is the only valid answer, in my opinion.  `e.Handled = true;` was insufficient; it was the `SuppressKeyPress` that did the trick.

Comment: textBox1_KeyUp will ding in this situation regardless of Handled or SuppressKeyPress

Comment: It doesn't happened with me. But is possible that you should do it to stop ding. In my case, I used the last visualStudio release. []s.

Comment: Works for me with ``ToolStripTextBox.KeyDown``. No other solution did. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work for me on my `textbox` and `KeyDown` event

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer requires a standard button placed on the form which is unpleasant.

Comment: This was enough for me. I didn't have access to suppress property because my event uses `KeyPressEventArgs`, not `KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK on vb net textbox. If it's multiline it does not beep, if it is not multiline it beeps and there is no way to prevent this apparenty

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  In my CRM login form, I capture and handle my hotkeys in the Form-level `KeyUp` event (with `KeyPreview = true`).  That keeps all my key handling code in one place, but there's no obvious way in KeyUp event handler to suppress the key event from getting re-processed by the textboxes.  

I use <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to submit the dialog, and the textbox re-processing was triggering the annoying *ding*.  And my my case, the login button is in a toolbar, so I can't set it as the `Form.AcceptButton`,

Comment: This worked for me in a .NET 4.6.2 C# winforms TextBox KeyDown event. No more audible noise.

Comment: This code will not stop the ding if there is an Application.DoEvents() line anywhere in the body of the function or any functions called from there.

Comment: I got it to work with my KeyUp event by leaving the 'doSomething()' in KeyUp, but adding a Keydown event that has the rest of the rest of  Lucio's 'ding suppression' code

Answer (score 64):

Try

```
textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed);

private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true; //this line will do the trick
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but it will only work if the focus is still on the TextBox. What about if the user presses `Tab` first?

Comment: @mdm Depends on the UI design. Perhaps OP only wants this action when focus is on the text box. That's pretty common.

Comment: If the user pressed Tab, the focus will no longer be on the TextBox, the next Contorl that will be Focused is the Button Control, which doesn't make that sound when you press Enter on it. :-)

Comment: @David, thanks for your example. I just tried it. And Whenever I put the *e.Handled = true* in the .KeyPress event, none of the other code executes. The only thing that happens is all the Text in the TextBox becomes selected (and I don't even have code that selects any text)

Comment: Lucio Fonseca's answer was the only one that I found to take care of the problem.

Comment: This also didn't work for me on my `textbox` and `KeyDown` event

Answer (score 23):

Just add `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` in your "if" statement.

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //If true, do not pass the key event to the underlying control.
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  //This will suppress the "ding" sound.*/

        // Perform search now.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can Use KeyPress instead of KeyUp or KeyDown its more efficient
and here's how to handle

```
  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

and say peace to the 'Ding'

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  e.Handled apparently disables the 'Ding'.  Making the 'Submit' button (in my case) the default, would not have worked for me because I wanted to handle the 'Enter' key differently for other text boxes on the form.<br/><br/>

By the way:  For this project I am using VB. so instead of casting e.KeyChar, I convert it:  

if e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter Then ....

Comment: Within the `KeyDown`, using `e.Handled` and `e.SuppressKeyPress` didn't work for me - still dinging.  But changing it as suggested here to use the `KeyPress' event and `e.Handled` did it nicely.

Answer (score 9):

Use `SuppressKeyPress` to stop continued processing of the keystroke after handling it.

```
public class EntryForm: Form
{
   public EntryForm()
   {
   }

   private void EntryTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
         e.Handled = true;
         e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
         // do some stuff

      }
      else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
          // do some stuff

      }
   }

   private void EntryTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
         // do some stuff

      }
      else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
      {
         // do some stuff

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On WinForms the Enter key causes a Ding sound because the form property AcceptButton is not specified.
If you don't need an AcceptButton the ding sound can be suppressed by setting the form KeyPreview to true and enter the following KeyPress event:

```
private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

No matter what control is active, there will be no more ding sound when pressing the Enter key. Since the key event proccessing order is KeyDown, KeyPress and KeyUp the Enter key will still work for the KeyDown events for the controls.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this post while trying to handle a KeyDown this worked for me.

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
   e.SuppressKeyPress = True
   btnLogIn.PerformClick()
End If
```

Supressing the Key Press stops the event from being sent to the underlying control. This should work if you're manually handling everything that the enter key will be doing within that textbox. Sorry about the Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#txtSomething").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {

            e.Handled = true; //This will prevent the "ding" sound

            //Write the rest of your code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very little chance anyone gets to this answer but some other answers are truly scary. Suppressing event on `KeyDown` kills 2 additional events in one strike. Setting `e.Handled` property to `true` is useless in this context. 
The best way is to set `Form.AcceptButton` property to the actual Search Button.
There is also another way of utilizing `Enter` key - some people may want it to act as `TAB` button. To do that, add a new `Button`, set its `Location` property outside of the `Form` area (i.e. `(-100, -100)`) - setting `Visible` property to `false` may disable `Button` handlers in some cases. Set `Form.AcceptButton` property to your new button. In `Click` event handler add following code 
`this.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true)`

Now, you may want to transfer `focus` only when `focus` it on `TextBox` you may want to either test `ActiveControl` type or use `e.Supress` property in event handlers of controls not meant to use `Enter` as `TAB`
That's it. You don't even need to capture `e.KeyCode`

Answer (score 0):

Set your Search button's [IsDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.isdefault.aspx) property to `true`. This will make it a default button and it will be auto-clicked when Enter is pressed.

Comment: From the docs you linked to `To specify the default button of a form, set the AcceptButton property of the form to the desired button.`

Comment: Yes, I've investigated this myself. It seems both approaches are interchangeable. `AcceptButton` seems more stylish, but I'm used to `IsDefault` myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well I lived with this problem long enough and looked it up here.

After thinking about this for quite some time and wanting the simplest way to fix it I came up with the easiest but not so elegant way to fix it.

Here is what I did.

1. Put 2 invisible buttons "Ok" and "Cancel" on the form.
2. Set the AcceptButton and CancelButton Property on the form to the invisible buttons.
3. Added no code to the buttons!

This solved all the secondary problems listed in this thread including the ToolStripMenu. My biggest complaint was the BindingNavigator, when I would enter a record number into the Current position to navigate to and pressed enter.

As per the original question in which the programmer wanted a search function when the enter button was pressed I simply put the search code in the invisible OK Button!

So far this seems to solve all problems but as we all know with Visual Studio, something will probably crop up.

The only other possible elegant way I could think of would be to write a new keystroke handling class which is way to much work for most of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your textbox multi-line to true then handle the Enter key press.

```
private void yourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
    }

//then write your TextBox codes
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the textbox properties for an multiline textbox and it works for me.

Comment: Answer was already stated below on 22-feb. You have to take care of [enter] too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` solution, it works fine by itself. Setting `SuppressKeyPress` to true also sets `Handled` to true, so there's no need to use `e.Handled= true;`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help:

Using KeyDown instead of KeyPress

```cs
private void AdvancedSearch_TXT_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                AdvancedSearch_TXT.Clear();
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
```

`e.SupressKeyPress` will do the trick

Comment: any affiliation with the channel in the video you linked to? ([/help/promotion](/help/promotion))

Comment: @user No. Just saw it suitable for people to see the idea vividly

Answer (score 0):

The `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` solution in the KeyDown event handler did not work for me since I have an `Application.DoEvents()` action called somewhere in the handler.
(I know there is some hesitation using `DoEvents()`, but I could not find another solution)

I could eliminate the `ding` sound by just setting the `TextBox.MultiLine` property
`TextBox1.Multiline` which allows the Enter key.  Since the Enter key executes the handler, the user cannot enter multi-lines in this case anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
void RTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //do ...
        bool temp = Multiline;
        Multiline = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        Multiline = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a redundant answer with only code, no explanation. Also, all of the `Multiline` code is completely irrelevant.