# Can you disable system sounds for a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I would like to disable some or all system sounds for a .NET 3.5 application.

I cannot find anything around `System.Media.SystemSounds` that turns off sound settings that the user has chosen via the control panel.

**[Edit]**
This is more for the Exlamation type sounds on certain message boxes we display.  Would really like a mute for a form or dialog.

Comment: If you're using system features that the user has configured to make sound, why would you want to do otherwise?

Comment: Couldn't resist...  Its called the mute button :)

Comment: If your looking to disable that *ding* in a text box, you could use the following solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290967/stop-the-ding-when-pressing-enter

Answer (score 2):

By definition, they are *system* sounds, not *application* sounds. Disabling all of them would therefore disable them for other applications, as well. Would you like using an application that arbitrarily disabled all your system sounds?

Without knowing which *specific* system sounds you're disabling, it's impossible to give you a more direct answer other than to simply mute the speakers.

Comment: I believe the OP was asking if you can mark the application such that windows generates no system sounds for it.