# Silence ding sound when handling KeyUp on TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using this to allow cursor progressing to next `TextBox` on a `WinForm`:

```
private void GoToNextControl(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly if not for a "ding" sound when I press enter. How could I "silence" the ding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290967/stop-the-ding-when-pressing-enter

Comment: @Mitch - I've seen that post. I can't use FormAcceptButton. I'm traversing multiple textboxes with subsequent TabIndexes. I'd have to make that button invisible and attach the method to it - it's not too professional...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ding" sound comes from unhandled Form event. On your Form:
 1. Add a button, set its `Visible` property to `false`
 2. Add `OnClick` event handler to that button. Keep the method empty
 3. Set Form's `AcceptButton` property to the new button.
That's it. "Ding" will be gone.

Answer (score 7):

Setting `SuppressKeyPress` to `true` in the handler should do it:

```
private void GoToNextControl(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Make sure your handler is hooked up to the `KeyDown` event, as this won't work in `KeyUp`.