# Suppress Key "Bing" with KeyPressEvent?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, keydown

Within our application, there is a usercontrol, which allows to enter a number (inside a `numericupdown`) followed by a `combobox` which allows to select the SI-Prefix (`[p, n, µ, m, -, k, M, G, T]` small to big)

Now, for easier usage, I thought it would be nice to capture the `KeyPress`-Event on the `numericUpDown` and set the `combobox` accordingly. (If `m` is pressed, select `mili (m)`, if `G` is pressed, select `Giga (G)`)

This works flawless with the following handler / selector:

```
 private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            //Check, if its valid for si prefixes. 
            if (this.siSelector1.TrySelect(e.KeyChar)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `TrySelect` does nothing but the following:

```
public Boolean TrySelect(Char chr)
    {
        var entry = this.comboBox_siPrefix.Items.Cast<KeyValuePair<String,Double>>().Where(e => e.Key.Contains("(" + chr + ")")).FirstOrDefault();

        if (!entry.Equals(new KeyValuePair<String, Double>()))
        {
            this.comboBox_siPrefix.SelectedItem = entry;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That's fine, but everytime the user hears a "BING" whenever a non-numeric Key is pressed on the `numericupdown`.

I read about `e.SuppressKeyPress`, which unfortunately isn't available with `KeyPressEventArgs` - it's only available for `KeyEventArgs`.

So, trying the whole thing with the `KeyDown`-Event works. (No "BING") - but I wasn't able to capture capital keys, as every `KeyDown` will fire the Event immediately...

```
 private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        if (char.IsLetter(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode)[0]))
        {
            //Check, if its valid for si prefixes. 
            if (this.siSelector1.TrySelect(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode)[0]))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a duplicate: [Stop the 'Ding' when pressing Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290967/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech No, as `Keys.Enter` is a single key, which works with `KeyDown`-Event as the example shows. `SHIFT+G` is captured through `KeyPress`-Event, which lacks the `e.SuppressKeyPress`-Property.

Comment: I don't get the problem.  If the user presses a key that you are not happy with it then it goes Ding.  If you never want to hear the dingaling then always set e.Handled = true for non-numeric characters.  SuppressKeyPress is irrelevant, the KeyPress event was already raised.  KeyDown is not a good idea on a foreign keyboard layout.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, but in this case - on the `numericupdown` i'm happy with valid letters such as `m, k, G,T...` cause they should be send to another control for convinience - So I don't want a "Bing". `Handled=true` (Google it!) Does not remove the BING for `numericupdown` fields. (Bug or feature?) Only `e.SuppressKeyPress` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a way:

When Using `KeyDown`-Event, you can use `e.Modifiers` to check, if another key is down'd at the same time.

I dunno why, but for the `KeyDown`-Event `e.KeyValue` as well as `e.KeyCode` always return the CAPITAL version of the key.

So, I modified the handler to convert every char to lower-case, and only convert it to upper-Case if `SHIFT` is pressed at the same time:

Works - no "BING" (for valid SI-Prefixes). :-)

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        char c = char.ToLower(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyValue)[0]); 
        if (char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            //Caps? 
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
            {
                c = char.ToUpper(c);
            }

            //Check, if its valid for si prefixes.
            if (this.siSelector1.TrySelect(c))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The above solution does not apply for `µ` (CTRL+ALT+m or ALT GR+m)

---

Update: This is not 100%, but I didn't get it by now:

- IF the ALT-Key is pressed, The Char-Code always reports a "M".

---

Update 2:

---

So, I had to exclude the "m" from beeing matched with `char.isLetter()` (if `alt` is pressed) and finally add another check.

I found, that comparing `e.KeyValue==77` worked as expected, while comparing `c=='m'` didn't... (then `µ` was inserted into the `numericupdown`, which it shouldn't)

`if (ctrl && alt && c=='m')`:

[image]

`if (ctrl && alt && e.KeyValue==77)`

[image]

Dunno why - Ideas?

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        char c = char.ToLower(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyValue)[0]);

        Boolean ctrl = e.Control;
        Boolean alt = e.Alt;
        Boolean shift = e.Shift;
        int keyPadStart = (int)Keys.NumPad0;
        int keyPadEnd = (int)Keys.NumPad9;

        if (e.KeyValue >= keyPadStart && e.KeyValue <= keyPadEnd)
        {
            //send to numeric updown. 
            return;
        }

        if (char.IsLetter(c) && !alt)
        {
            if (shift) c = char.ToUpper(c);

            //Check, if its valid for si prefixes.
            if (this.siSelector1.TrySelect(c))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        //not working: if (ctrl && alt && c=='m')
        if (ctrl && alt && e.KeyValue==77)
        {
            //Check, if its valid for si prefixes.
            if (this.siSelector1.TrySelect('µ'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }

        }
    }
```