# Stop "ding" when pressing Enter? (e.SuppressKeyPress is not recognized)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've already read through this thread: [Stop the 'Ding' when pressing Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290967/stop-the-ding-when-pressing-enter)

I'm having no luck with e.SuppressKeyPress. I get an error "'KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SuppressKeyPress' ..."

I am VERY VERY VERY VERY new to this. I cannot understate this enough. Please explain like I'm 5 years old. Sorry..

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015 to create a Windows Form with C#.net.

Here is my code:

```
    private void answer_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            CheckAnswer();
        }
    }
```

I tried putting e.SuppressKeyPress = true; after my CheckAnswer(); function but I get red squigglies indicating it doesn't know what that is.

Why?

I've had no formal training in using C#.net and I'm missing the foundation of how this is all supposed to work which is messing me up I think. :(

Comment: You are referring to the `KeyDown`/`KeyUp` events. The `KeyEventArgs` parameter has that property: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: You are using the `Key_Press` event. Try using the `Key_Down` Event.

Comment: `KeyDown` + `e.SuppressKeyPress = true; e.Handled = true;`

Comment: You can un-ding it with KeyPress as well, just takes e.Handled = true.

Comment: Thank you! @HansPassant that worked easily lol.